# Triggering GET method on form submit when POST method is specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, http-method

I have a form_tag to which I specify a POST method but each time I submit the form it is trying to use the GET method. Here is my form :

```
 <%= form_tag (refund_path(subscription), :method => "post") do %>
                  <%= hidden_field_tag :subscription_id_refund, subscription.id %>
                  <%= submit_tag "Rembourser ce joueur", id: "export", class: "btn btn-warning"%>
                  <% end -%>
```

here is my route :

```
 post 'refunds/:subscription_id', to: "subscriptions#refund", as: "refund"
```

here is my method :

```
def refund
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:subscription_id_refund])
    if mangopay_refund
      @subscription.status == "refused"
      redirect_to
      flash[:notice] = "Vous avez bien procéder au remboursemend de #{@subscription.user.full_name}. Celui-ci ne participe plus au tournoi"
    else
      redirect_to
      flash[:warning] = "Le remboursement n'a pas pu etre effectué. Merci de réessayer plus tard"
    end
  end
```

Do you know how to fix that ?

Comment: Why are you using `form_tag` rather than `form_for`?

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: I can't see any issue aside from a few syntaxes.  Remove the `=` in the `form_tag`.  Can you make sure that you're submitting the correct form.  You may also want to add the server log for the GET request you're getting.

Comment: sorry just realised I was missing the redirect_to

Answer (score 0):

The method for the form defaults to POST.So remove `:method => "post"` options and try.

```
 <%= form_tag(refund_path(subscription)) do %>
```

Reference : [form_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag)

Comment: sorry just realised I was missing the redirect_to